# Put element after absolute div element

Tags: css, html

I have an absolute slider div including images and some arrows, When I add another div, I expect it appear after last div (that is absolute), but it places behind absolute div, I know it's because absolute position is beyond box flow, and I just want to know how to put new div after last absolute div, widout giving margin-top?

HTML code:

```
<div id="next">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div id="slider">
       <div class="slide">
           <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div id="advertises">

</div>
```

Css code:

```
#slider{
position: relative;
margin-top: -17px;
}
.slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#next, #prev{
    width: 70px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#next{
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: right;
}
#prev{
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}
#advertises{
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #101010;
    display: flex;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bxs64zf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to wrap the slider, then add `overflow:auto` and `height:400px`

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -17px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#next,
#prev {
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#next {
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
}

#prev {
  margin-left: 25px;
  float: left;
}

#advertises {
  clear: both;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="next">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="prev">
    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="advertises">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use absolute positioning you lose the ability to relate that to other elements. That is, you can place a element relatively to other when the other is absolute.

You should try to look for another solution that fits your intention. I don't see the reason to not use a "normal" positioning.